# Restore deleted sidebar icons after moving user folder to another drive

Tags: finder, restore, icon, macos, sidebar

I moved my user directory to another hard drive, as I am using an HDD (for Data) beside my SSD (for system).
After that, all the sidebar icons in Finder got lost and now that are just folder icons.

I tried to drag&drop the icns-files from
/System/Library/CoreServices/CoreTypes.bundle/Contents/Resources/

in the informations-window of the corresponding folder. But that just change the appearance of the folders, not the sidebar icons.

How can I restore the icons? Maybe someone could upload empty folders with the right icons, so that I could copy&paste them in my folders?

Comment: What Icons? were they customized ? or just standard OS X?

Comment: Standard OS X Yosemite icons. They got automatically deleted, after I moved the user directory to another volume. So the best for me would be, if somebody could upload empty folders with original icons for Movies, Pictures, Downloads, etc.

Comment: I can do that, but what you going to do with them ?

Comment: Right click on your empty folder, get info and then copy the icon from the top left. Then right click on my folder with the empty icon, get info and paste the icon. In the past I did this already but I only have those empty folders for mavericks. In Yosemite the icons changed. :( I would really appreciate your help! It would help me a lot!

Comment: I am still on Mavericks and those Icons are in the /System/Library/CoreServices/CoreTypes.bundle/Contents/Resources/

Comment: Right, I tried to use them already by dragging them on the icon in "get info". It changes the folder icon but has no impact on the sidebar icons unfortunately. Maybe someone else is on Yosemite already and could help me?

Comment: Did you try to restart after change.

Comment: Yes, I did. Tried everything but no luck.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

Go to your Finder *Go* menu hold the option key and choose *Library*. Then go to the *Preferences* folder and trash these files:

- `com.apple.finder.plist`
- `com.apple.sidebarlists.plist`

Then *restart* (You will have to reset a some finder prefs the way you like them).