# Restore Downloads icon to Finder Sidebar

Tags: finder, icon

So I symlinked my Downloads folder from my boot drive to an external HDD I always keep connected to my mac. I deleted the original downloads folder from my home folder and replaced it with a symlink to a new folder on my HDD.

This works perfectly, except that in Finder, the sidebar icon is now a folder:

[image: no download icon]

When it should look like this:

[image: download icon]

Operating system is High Sierra 10.13.6

Comment: I think you dragged downloads folder in the finder sidebar to create a folder shortcut. Remove it and try from finder preferences.

Comment: @ankiiiiiii tried this but nothing appears in the sidebar (original download folder is deleted, only a symlink remains)

Comment: Okay one more check to see if original downloads folder is deleted or not. Go to finder -> Press cmd + up arrow to navigate up to reach username folder. You should see a list of folders like Applications, Desktop, Pictures etc. Now see what icon does the downloads folder has.

Answer (score 1):

Even though what you need is very little, there seems to be no easy workaround except for the SIMBL plugin:

[How can I change Finder's sidebar icons in OS X El Capitan?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/242358/how-can-i-change-finders-sidebar-icons-in-os-x-el-capitan?answertab=active#tab-top)

As an experiment I uploaded my downloads folder to google drive. You can try downloading it and see if it works:

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1U3dY4N_ZDLtnq93yoKVYVi4F5WqBaa8i?usp=sharing

Comment: hi, thanks. i tried the google drive sample provided but unfortunately it did not work. i am trying SIMBL method now. do you happen to have **colorfulSidebar9 No Icons.bundle.zip**? that is dead link on linked page. Thanks

Comment: I did also try installing the colour icons in SIMBL, which did work, but changes every icon, which is not what i preferred :/

Comment: I found another possible answer: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/151043/restore-deleted-sidebar-icons-after-moving-user-folder-to-another-drive

Comment: Thanks you but i tried that too and didn't work . That's okay I will just keep it as it is